# Calling make from within a makefile

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, multiple-makefiles

I have a Makefile which works perfectly called from a new shell, i.e.:

```
make -C /dir/
```

However, if I call this Makefile from *another* Makefile, it fails due to some complicated dependency issues. Make clearly has knowledge of the nested calls, evident by the print of `make[1]:` etc, and I suspect make is somehow sharing variables with its child process.

Is there anyway to call a *clean* make from within a Makefile? If my build works from a clean shell, it should be possible to call it from another Makefile without addressing the horrors inside the script! :)

Thanks!

Comment: It's not easy. Do you mean that makefile_1 fails when it is called from a *particular* makefile_2, or from *any* other makefile (such as a trivial one that does nothing else)?

Comment: Hmmmm, odd. Compare the output of `make -p` in each case. (As a matter of course I always run _make_ with `-Rr` and `--warn`—YMMV.)

Answer (score 13):

`make` indeed shares some of its environment when it is recursively called. As suggested in https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Options_002fRecursion.html#Options_002fRecursion, you might want to write your recursive call that way:

```
sub-make:
        $(MAKE) -C /dir/ MAKEFLAGS=
```

and see if it helps. You can also control the variables that are exported to the sub-make by using `export` and `unexport` directives (https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Variables_002fRecursion.html#Variables_002fRecursion)

Answer (score 1):

It was a few environment variables in the caller make that broke the callee make (CFLAGS etc...)

My solution was to diff the environment at a clean shell and from the point of call. I then manually added the problem variables to a list and created some save_env/restore_env scripts.

Thanks!